# "Cannot convert 'MyClass' to 'bool'" Error in Template Programming

Tags: c++, templates

I am playing around with templates and have tried the following but get 'Cannot convert 'MyClass' to 'bool' error?

```
#include "Unit2.h"
using namespace std;

template <class T>
T GetMax (T a, T b) {
  T result;
  result = (a > b) ? a : b;
  return (result);
}

int main () {
  MyClass k1( 10, "A" );
  MyClass k2( 50, "B" );
  MyClass k3( 0,"" );
  k3 = GetMax<MyClass>(k1,k2);

  cout << k3.GetName() << endl;

  return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have defined a > operator for myclass as follows:

```
MyClass& MyClass::operator>(MyClass &rhs)
{
    MyClass& rkReturn = ( m_iSize > rhs.m_iSize ) ? *this : rhs;
    return rkReturn; 
}
```

Comment: Good question though except for the title.  You showed the error message and all relevant code!  There's even a question mark!

Comment: @Joe: Did you get your answer? Which one was it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `>` operator should return a `bool`, not a `MyClass` reference.

Answer (score 3):

Your `operator>` returns a `MyClass&` instead of a `bool`. By using it in the conditional operator, the compiler is trying to coerce the returned `MyClass` to a `bool`.

Change

```
MyClass& MyClass::operator>(MyClass &rhs)
{
    MyClass& rkReturn = ( m_iSize > rhs.m_iSize ) ? *this : rhs;
    return rkReturn; 
}
```

to

```
bool MyClass::operator>(const MyClass &rhs) const
{
    return m_iSize > rhs.m_iSize;
}
```

Comment: While you're correcting the `operator>`, note that it should be a `const` function.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `x ? y : z` requires x to be convertable to a `bool` type.  You give it the expression `(a > b)`, which calls your operator `MyClass& MyClass::operator>(MyClass &rhs)`, which returns a `MyClass` by reference.  The compiler cannot convert this reference to a `bool`, and gets confused.  `MyClass::operator>(MyClass &rhs)` should return a `bool`.

```
bool MyClass::operator>(MyClass &rhs) const //also, it should be a const function
{
    return m_iSize > rhs.m_iSize 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `>` operator needs to return a `bool` (or something that can be automatically converted to a `bool`, such as an `int`), not a `MyClass&`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `bool` from `operator>`.

So try this:

```
bool MyClass::operator>(const MyClass &rhs)
{
    return m_iSize > rhs.m_iSize;
}
```

It would be better if you make this a `const` function, by putting the keyword on the right side of the function, as shown below:

```
bool MyClass::operator>(const MyClass &rhs) const 
{                                        // ^^^^^ this makes the function const
    return m_iSize > rhs.m_iSize;
}
```

Put `const` on the  declaration also.

Answer (score 1):

operator> should be declared/defined to return bool, not MyClass&.

Comment: But isn't this the power of templates, for example..T result;
  result = (a > b) ? a : b;
result is of type T which is MyClass, why can't i return that?

Comment: In general, yes, a method's return type can be a template parameter. But consider the semantics of "greater than"... any other result type than bool would be strange.

Comment: @JoeSaddigh: In the terenary operator `(a > b) ? a : b;` the result of `(a>b)` is expected to be an `bool` and not `MyClass` and hence your `>` operator should return a `bool`.

Comment: @Joe: `a` and `b` are `MyClass`, sure, and that's what gets returned. But in order for the conditional to work, `a > b` quite obviously has to be a `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

`operator >` should return bool and not `MyClass &` like this:

```
bool MyClass::operator>(MyClass &rhs)
{
    return m_iSize > rhs.m_iSize;
}
```

Comment: Sorry ... there are so many posts coming into this thread, I editing the wrong post by accident.

Comment: Thank you all for your posts!! I see exactly what you mean I had a moment of madness. I was getting confused about all of the Ts and stuff lol... In addition I copied most of the syntax from the assignment operator which naturally returns a ref. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
bool MyClass::operator>(MyClass &rhs)
{
    return m_iSize > rhs.m_iSize ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `operator>` for `MyClass` should simply define whether one instance of the class is greater than the other, and it should return type `bool`, not type `MyClass&`.  Modify it so that it looks like the following:

```
bool MyClass::operator>(const MyClass &rhs) const
{
    return m_iSize > rhs.m_iSize; 
}
```

This will now properly test whether the current instance of `MyClass` is larger than the `MyClass` instance on the right-hand side of the `>` operator in such an expression.